# Does Redis Hget key value loads the hash contents into main memory

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I have my java on separate kubernetes pod and redis is on separate ip address each have their separate memory

Have created one hash in redis as below

hashfunction key value.
value is a set of string

this hash function can contain millions of value

Now while getting it from redis , I am using the Hget command
hget hashfunction key

only need to get for one key.
Need to know whether this operation will be executed in redis only and it will not be loading the full hash in java memory?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will only receive the value that you retrieved from the key; this will be resolved server side in Redis and only the value will be transmitted back to your Java application. The Java application will not see the complete content stored under the key, just the value you're retrieving.

You can see exactly what gets returned by [looking at what the protocol itself returns](https://redis.io/commands/hget):

```
redis> HSET myhash field1 "foo"
(integer) 1
redis> HGET myhash field1
"foo"
redis> HGET myhash field2
(nil)
redis>
```